# How to find the proper SDK version for Eclipse Neon?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

So, I migrated from Java 6 to Java 8 and from Eclipse Kapler to Neon. Before I used `eclipse-SDK-3.7.1-linux-gtk-x86_64` for the SDK in my `build.xml`.

Now I'm trying to figure out which SDK I need to use and where should I download it. Should it be `eclipse-SDK-4.6-linux-gtk-x86_64`? How do I know which version of SDK is the needed for Eclipse Neon and JDK 8?

Answer (score 1):

Neon was indeed version 4.6, but it was released in June of 2016, meaning it's old enough to have been [archived](https://archive.eclipse.org/). The current release, 2020-03, is capable of writing for Java 8 just fine.

Comment: So it's ok to use Neon which is old version of eclipse with the newest version of SDK?

Comment: It might, but why use Neon at this point? Any bugs you find will not be fixed with a new Neon service release.

Comment: The newest Eclipse does support Java 8?

Comment: Yes. And this sentence is just to be long enough for StackOverflow to accept.